# jQuery inArray - problems

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I have a variable `a` with the value:

```
1
```

Then I have an array `b` with the values:

```
[1, 2]
```

Why does `$.inArray(a, b)` give me a -1? I should be getting `0`, right?

Comment: Mind posting your code? This should work in theory, but maybe your implementation has a bug.

Comment: You do get `0`. http://jsfiddle.net/S39Qt/ Please provide actual code that has been verified to reproduce the issue. After asking 299 questions, I'd think you'd know how to present a quality question here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Exactly what you described gives me `0`<sup>[[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yDHVn/)]</sup>:

```
var a = 1, b = [1, 2];
alert($.inArray(a, b)); // alerts "0"
```

However, I can replicate your results when I do this (as suggested by IAbstractDownvoteFactory):

```
var a = 1, b = ["1", "2"];
alert($.inArray(a, b)); // alerts "-1"
```

```
var a = "1", b = [1, 2];
alert($.inArray(a, b)); // alerts "-1"
```

`.inArray` only finds matches that are the same type as what you're searching with (they're compared with `===`). If you can't make your input data the right format, you can do it yourself:

To convert `a` to a number:

```
a = +a; // or a = Number(a);
```

To convert all elements of `b` to numbers:

```
for (var i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
    b[i] = +b[i];
}
```

Comment: OK, something else has to be wrong. I'm trying to test the code. The values `1` and `[1,2]` come from a server as JSON. Does that matter? I was wondering if this could be a type issue somehow.

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie: I added IAbstractDownvoteFactory's suggestion to my post: if one is a string and the other is a number, it won't find it.

Comment: I can't post the code as it's accessing an unsecured API at the moment. When I console.debug the array, I get `[1, 2]` and not ["1", "2"]. How do I test the type of an item in an array?

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie: `typeof item` is a start.

Comment: it was a type issue. `a` was actually a string. I type casted it per your suggestion. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than convert to numbers it may be better to convert to strings, such as in an instance where you are usings ids for say a plot where in some case they will numeric entity id and in others case a string, e.g. country code for United Kingdom is GB.

Ensure all values are set as strings

```
Arr[] = mixedValue.toString();
```

And then always ensure your comparison needle is a string

```
if ($.inArray(needle.toString(), Arr) === -1) {
    // nope
} else {
    // yep
}
```